# If a mass $m$ is connected with a string to an axis and spin around it, why does gravity not bring it towards the axis?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, string

Looking in an inertial frame only, forces on the mass are tension and gravity, neither seems to be  in the vertical direction. So how come the mass can remain spinning in one plane?

Comment: The orientation is unclear. Is the axis horizontal or vertical?

Comment: How is it not clear that it is vertical, if it says that tension is not in the vertical and it is perpendicular to the axis?

Comment: at least 3 people agree that it is not clear which is a pretty high number given that it has only been viewed 10 times and some of those are multiple views from the same person. Please respond by editing the question so that it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're thinking of a vertical axis of rotation and vertical gravity.

If the string would be exactly horizontal, gravity would indeed pull the mass down. However, there will be a stable situation where the string is somewhat downward (i.e. it is sweeping out a cone). Now, the tension has a vertical component that cancels gravity, and the remaining horizontal component gives the required centripetal force $m\omega^2 r$. The angle depends on the gravitational acceleration, angular velocity and length of the string (it's easy to work out).

Comment: Yea but, intuitively, this doesn't explain why is it easier to hold a rotating mass on a long stick for example, then just picking it up

Comment: @Ezio I'm not sure I understand your remark. If you're holding and rotating a stick with a string with a mass attached and swinging it around, you have to provide the force counteracting gravity, since the string tension pulls the rod downward. If you claim that it feels lighter, I doubt that. But it may be due to the fact that if the mass swings close to vertical, the horizontal component of the string tension is pretty large and still provided by your arm and hand, so that the graviational part might be lost in the "noise". You might try to lift the arragement at different ...

Comment: rotational speeds (from $\omega=0$, i.e. hanging straight down, to very fast and nearly horizontal) to gauge the difference.